# Converting cv::FileStorage to CvFileStorage

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to "read" the content contained in a "cv::FileStorage" into a CvRTrees (one of the CvStatModel implementations).

The "read" function needs a CvFileStorage* and a CvFileNode* (second parameter)

It seems that I can get a CvFileStorage from the cv::FileStorage, but I cannot get the CvFileNode*.

The functions (fs.getFirstTopLevelNode().node and fs["someName"]) both return a "const CvFileNode*" instead of a "CvFileNode*", and (the other solution) I cannot reach the inside of the CvFileStorage*.

There are the solutions that I am trying so far:

```
string s = "some stuffs" // in the real code, "s" is actually exported from a rtree ("write" function)
cv::FileStorage fs(s, cv::FileStorage::READ + cv::FileStorage::MEMORY);
CvRTrees* rtree = new CvRTrees();
rtree->read(fs.fs,fs.fs->cvGetFileNodeByName("mytree"));
```

Error:

```
error C2027: use of undefined type 'CvFileStorage'
```

The definition of CvFileStorage is: typedef struct CvFileStorage CvFileStorage;

or

```
string s = "some stuffs"
cv::FileStorage fs(s, cv::FileStorage::READ + cv::FileStorage::MEMORY);
CvRTrees* rtree = new CvRTrees();
rtree->read(fs.fs,fs["mytree"].node);
```

Error:

```
error C2664: 'CvRTrees::read' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const CvFileNode *' to 'CvFileNode *'
```

Both of the solutions fail at the compilation (always because of the second argument of "read").

Do you guys know how to deal with that?

Thanks in advance.

Achoum

Comment: So, let's start from [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/xml_yaml_persistence.html#FileStorage)... Watching the game, so give me some time... :)

Comment: It's "some stuffs" something else (namely, a valid file name), or it is really "some stuffs"?

Comment: What's rtree? Can you put it's declaration? Anyway, what happens if you put only MEMORY and not READ?

Comment: Ah, ok, it fails at compilation, that was important. Which is the error? [Here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/xml_yaml_persistence.html#FileStorage) or maybe [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/random_trees.html#CvRTrees%20:%20public%20CvStatModel) is the rest of the documentation

Comment: And the read is [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/statistical_models.html#index-0)

Comment: To be safe, in the first one put this `fs.fs->cvGetFileNodeByName("mytree")` like this `(fs.fs)->cvGetFileNodeByName("mytree")`

Answer (score 1):

yea, a bit clumsy here, you have to use the overloaded * operator to access a CvFileNode from FileStorage:

```
FileStorage fs("my.yml", FileStorage::WRITE);
dtree.write(*fs,"dst");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `load`, not `read` http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/statistical_models.html#cvstatmodel-load:

```
Loads the model from a file.

void CvStatModel::load(const char* filename, const char* name=0 )

The method load loads the complete model state with the specified name
(or default model-dependent name) from the specified XML or YAML file.
The previous model state is cleared by CvStatModel::clear()
```

If this is not possible, correct to:

```
rtree->read(&fs,&(fs.getFirstTopLevelNode()) );
```

This should at least compile.

If it does, it seems that what you want is this:

```
rtree->read(&fs,&(fs["mytree"]) );
```

Otherwise, try the obsolete one:

```
rtree->read(fs.operator*(),&(fs.getFirstTopLevelNode()) );
```

But I am not sure this is the correct way of calling it...

.

Links to documentation:

1. [cv::FileStorage](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/xml_yaml_persistence.html#FileStorage)
2. [CvRTrees](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/random_trees.html#CvRTrees%20:%20public%20CvStatModel)
3. [CvStatModel::read](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/statistical_models.html#cvstatmodel-read)

Comment: I would love being able to use load/save, but the model (trees) are not saved in filed, and I would like to avoid using temporary files.

Comment: It does not compile actually:
&fs is a cv:FileStorage
and the function wants a CvFileStorage

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem (read is more general than load, since you can store several structures in the same FileStorage).

I found this solution:

```
FileStorage::operator*
// Returns the obsolete C FileStorage structure.

C++: CvFileStorage* FileStorage::operator*()
C++: const CvFileStorage* FileStorage::operator*() const
// Returns: Pointer to the underlying C FileStorage structure
```

So just calling `*fs` should work.